# problem in loading image from Firebase in RecyclerView

Tags: java, android, firebase, android-recyclerview

I was trying to make an app. I am using a Horizontal RecyclerView in an Activity which was named as CardTestActivity. I am saving two types of data, first one is name and second one is imageUri in my Firebase Database. Here is the screenshot of my Firebase Database :- [image: Screenshot]

I am facing a problem like i am getting names in my RecyclerView but instead of getting imageUri  ,I am getting null. I have a ViewHolder and a adapter class which was i am using in my RecyclerView.
I tried to change DataClass but i am getting same problem. I have provided my code below :-

Here is my code:-

CardTestAdapter :-

```
public class CardTestAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<CardTestAdapter.CardTestViewHolder> {
    private Context mContext;
    private List<CardTestData> mData;

    public CardTestAdapter(Context context , List<CardTestData> data) {
        mContext = context;
        mData = data;
    }

    @NonNull
    @Override
    public CardTestViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(@NonNull ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View v = LayoutInflater.from(mContext).inflate(R.layout.card_test_recycler_view , parent ,false);
        return new CardTestViewHolder(v);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(@NonNull CardTestViewHolder holder, int position) {

        CardTestData testData = mData.get(position);

        holder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(mContext, "" + testData.getImageUri(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        });

        Glide.with(mContext)
                .asBitmap()
                .load(testData.getImageUri())
                .into(holder.imageView);

        holder.name.setText(testData.getName());
    }

    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return mData.size();
    }

    public class CardTestViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        TextView name;
        ImageView imageView;

        public CardTestViewHolder(@NonNull View itemView) {
            super(itemView);
            name = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_test_name);
            imageView = itemView.findViewById(R.id.card_test_image);
        }
    }
}
```

CardTestData :-

```
public class CardTestData {
    private String name;
    private String imageUri;

    public CardTestData(){

    }

    public CardTestData(String name , String imageUri) {
        this.name = name;
        this.imageUri = imageUri;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return  name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name =  name;
    }


    public String getImageUri() {
        return imageUri;
    }

    public void setImageUri(String iamgeUri) {
        this.imageUri = getImageUri();
    }
}
```

My CardTestActivity :-

```
public class CardTestActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    CardView cv;
    private RecyclerView mRecyclerView;
    private List<CardTestData> mData;
    private ValueEventListener mListener;
    private DatabaseReference mDataRef;
    private CardTestAdapter mAdatper;

    @SuppressLint("ClickableViewAccessibility")
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_card_test);
        cv = findViewById(R.id.new_cardView);

        cv.setCardBackgroundColor(Color.RED);

        mDataRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("newReleasesData");
        mRecyclerView = this.findViewById(R.id.card_test_recyclerview);
        mRecyclerView.setHasFixedSize(true);
        LinearLayoutManager manager = new LinearLayoutManager(this , LinearLayoutManager.HORIZONTAL ,false);
        mRecyclerView.setLayoutManager(manager);
        mData = new ArrayList<>();
        mAdatper = new CardTestAdapter(this , mData);
        mRecyclerView.setAdapter(mAdatper);

        mListener = mDataRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                for (DataSnapshot postSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()){
                    CardTestData data = postSnapshot.getValue(CardTestData.class);
                    mData.add(data);
                }
                mAdatper.notifyDataSetChanged();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });

    }
}
```

Please help me retrieve image and please answer me if you have any solution.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are not setting the image in your model that you get from firebase rather you set default `null` all the time. Check below solution:

Instead of

```
public void setImageUri(String iamgeUri) { 
    this.imageUri = getImageUri(); 
}
```

Use

```
public void setImageUri(String iamgeUri) { 
    this.imageUri = iamgeUri; 
}
```